# Continuously Getting "Found no committed offset for partition 'topic-name-x' " for new consumer and consumer group

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, confluent-control-center

I am using "spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka" for my consumer, having AVRO topic.
it's new consumer with new consumer group. After running the application I am getting this log "**Found no committed offset for partition 'topic-name-x'**". **I read that** **it is expected to get this log for new consumer groups but even after that it's not consuming any messages.**

Having below config for consumer:

```
spring:
 cloud:
  function:
   definition: input
 stream:
  bindings:
    input-in-0:
      destination: topic-name
      group: group-name
  kafka:
    binder:
      autoCreateTopics: false
      brokers: broker-server
      configuration:
        security.protocol: SSL
        ssl.truststore.type: JKS
        ssl.truststore.location: 
        ssl.truststore.password: 
        ssl.keystore.type: JKS
        ssl.keystore.location: 
        ssl.keystore.password: 
        ssl.key.password: 
        request.timeout.ms:
        max.request.size: 
      consumerProperties:
        key.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
        value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
        schema.registry.url: url
        basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
        basic.auth.user.info: ${AUTH_USER}:${AUTH_USER_PASS}
        specific.avro.reader: true
        spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    bindings:
      input-in-0:
        consumer:
          autoCommitOffset: false
```

Why it's not able to consumer the messages??? I tried setting `resetOffsets: true, startOffset: earliest`.  But still no luck.